# filling a dateframe from a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I tried to create a date frame with lists:

```
lista_values  = [2983, 2983, 5652, 12375, 13055, 26180]
labels = ['00_04', '04_08', '08_12', '12_16', '16_20', '20_24']
lista_index = [datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 11, 0, 0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista_values,index=lista_index,columns=labels)
```

then my error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 6), indices imply (6, 1)
```

How can I create a data frame with these lists, for example? I really don't understand why is out of bounds here if the columns and labels have same length

Comment: Looks like you got your dimensions wrong. But your first concern should be to make that code more readable and always share some data we can try ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. Yeah maybe I should rewrite the question then... I can not understand because the lengs are the same so makes no sense so far

Comment: Seems simple but no one tries to help me

Comment: You posted your question not too long ago. It is still hard to follow. You should always aim to write a small code which I can easily copy and reproduce your error.

Comment: @AntonvBR oi agora coloquei somente o necessario. Now I have written only the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is this what you want? I flipped the dataframe with transpose (T).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

lista_values  = [2983, 2983, 5652, 12375, 13055, 26180]
labels = ['00_04', '04_08', '08_12', '12_16', '16_20', '20_24']
lista_index = [datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 11, 0, 0)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=lista_values, index=labels, columns = lista_index).T

df
```

Returns:

```
            00_04  04_08  08_12  12_16  16_20  20_24
2017-11-11   2983   2983   5652  12375  13055  26180
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am relieved but still dont understand why

Comment: @Mayra Thanks to you who rewrote your question. If you write them like this you get help much faster.